# Map ArrayList of Arraylist using index in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, filter

I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList<String>`

`ArrayList<String>` will be having the same size

I want to create new `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

For example:-

I have this list:-

```
[
    ["a", "1"],
    ["b", "1"],
    ["c", "1"]
]
```

and I want output as below :-

```
[
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["1", "1", "1"]
]
```

Comment: In matrix terminology, what you want is the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).  (Also, as a matter of style, it's usually much better to refer the interfaces instead of concrete implementations: `List<List<String>>`.)

Answer (score 2):

This will handle lists of arbitrary and uneven size.

Strategy: Remove the inner lists while adding original indices to each item. Group them by their original indices. Finally, strip the indices.

```
val pivoted = lists.flatMap { it.withIndex() }
    .groupBy { it.index }
    .values.map { list -> list.map { it.value } }
```

Console:

```
[[a, 1], [b, 2, β], [c, 3, γ]] // Input
[[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3], [β, γ]] // Output
```

Answer (score 1):

More generic way that can handle longer inner lists.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `Test groupByIndexed`() {
        val mapOfLists = arrayListOf(
                arrayListOf("a", "1"),
                arrayListOf("b", "2"),
                arrayListOf("c", "3")
            )
            .asSequence()
            .flatMap { it.asSequence() }
            .groupByIndexed { idx, _ ->
                idx % 2 // Use how many elements have each inner list
            }

        // Convert Map<List<String>> to desired ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
        val arrayListOfArrayLists = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()
        mapOfLists
            .asSequence()
            .map {
                ArrayList<String>().apply {
                    addAll(it.component2())
                }
            }
            .toCollection(arrayListOfArrayLists)



        Assertions.assertEquals(2, arrayListOfArrayLists.size)
        Assertions.assertEquals(arrayListOf("a", "b", "c"), arrayListOfArrayLists[0])
        Assertions.assertEquals(arrayListOf("1", "2", "3"), arrayListOfArrayLists[1])
    }

    private fun <T, K> Sequence<T>.groupByIndexed(keySelector: (Int, T) -> K): Map<K, List<T>> {
        val data = LinkedHashMap<K, MutableList<T>>()

        return foldIndexed(data) { idx, acc, str ->
            val key = keySelector(idx, str)
            val list = acc.getOrPut(key) { mutableListOf() }
            list.add(str)
            acc
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
@Test
fun rotate2dList() {
    val old = listOf(
            listOf("a", "1"),
            listOf("b", "1"),
            listOf("c", "1")
    )

    val N = old[0].size // determine size of new list

    val new = old
            .asSequence()
            .flatMap { it.asSequence() }
            .withIndex()
            .groupBy { it.index % N }
            .values
            .map { it.map { it.value } }

    assertEquals(N, new.size)
    assertEquals(listOf("a", "b", "c"), new[0])
    assertEquals(listOf("1", "1", "1"), new[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example in that way:

```
val lista = arrayListOf(
            arrayListOf("a","1"),
            arrayListOf("b", "1"),
            arrayListOf("c","1")
    )


    val newList = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()
    newList.add(
            lista.map { it[0] }.toMutableList() as ArrayList<String>
    )
    newList.add(lista.map { it[1] }.toMutableList() as ArrayList<String>)

    newList.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
[1, 1, 1]
```